# JavaFX Image cancel background loading

Tags: java, image, javafx, loading

In short; Is there a way to cancel / clear the background loading for JavaFX Images?

At one point in my code, I load a bunch of images. For performance reasons those are being loaded in the background with

```
public Image(String url, boolean backgroundLoading)
```

from the Images class.

The problem is that sometimes, user interaction causes the program to update the list of images (and not needing the previous ones) before loading of the previous ones is finished. At that point I'd like to cancel the background loading of the previous ones. Right now, it still loads the previous ones, causing longer loading time for the images actually needed.

See example below. When I get a new stream of sources before the old one is finished processing, it takes longer for the content to start displaying the images because it still is loading the previous ones (at least that's my guess).

```
List<ImageView> images = sources.map(source -> {
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(new Image(source.toUri().toString(), true));
    iv.setPreserveRatio(true);
    return iv;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
content.getChildren().setAll(images);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cancel the background loading of an `Image` with [`Image.cancel`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#cancel()).

> Cancels the background loading of this image.
>
> Has no effect if this image isn't loaded in background or if loading has already completed.